# Twilio verify.v2 can't verify a new phone number using the API

Tags: java, spring-boot, curl, twilio, sms

I'm trying to verify a new phone number to send SMS using an SMS service called Twilio. They have provided some API integration packages for JAVA developers and curl commands to verify a new phone number to send messages.

> My problem is when I request a verification OTP using :

```
 String command ="curl -X POST https://verify.twilio.com/v2/Services/" + SERVICE_SID + "/Verifications --data-urlencode To=+" + phone +
            " --data-urlencode Channel=sms -u " + ACCOUNT_SID + ":" + AUTH_TOKEN;

    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    process.getInputStream();
```

> It sends an OTP to the required phone. But when I submit the OTP using :

```
        String command ="curl -X POST https://verify.twilio.com/v2/Services/" + SERVICE_SID + "/Verifications --data-urlencode To=+" + phone +
            " --data-urlencode Code="+ otp +" -u " + ACCOUNT_SID + ":" + AUTH_TOKEN;
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    process.getInputStream();
```

> It gives 200 OK in the postman indicating the request was succeeded.
>   But when I try to send messages to that phone it gives me an error saying that the phone number is not verified.
>   And if I check the verified phone numbers in the Twilio console also the number is not visible there.

Here is the Verify.java (Service class) of my spring-boot application.

```
package com.cctv.sms.service;
import com.cctv.sms.SmsApplication;
import com.twilio.Twilio;
import com.twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.Message;
import com.twilio.type.PhoneNumber;
import com.twilio.rest.verify.v2.service.Verification;
import com.twilio.rest.verify.v2.Service;
import com.twilio.rest.verify.v2.service.VerificationCheck;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

@org.springframework.stereotype.Service
public class VerifyPhone implements VerificationService{
    String ACCOUNT_SID;// Account Security Identifier - sms service
    String AUTH_TOKEN;// Auth Token - sms service
    String SERVICE_SID;// verification service - Security identifier

    String servicePhone;// phone number act as the sender for the sms notifications

    private static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger("InfoLogging");
    public String requestVerification(long phone) throws IOException {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        InputStream inputStream = SmsApplication.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("application.properties");
        props.load(inputStream);
        ACCOUNT_SID = props.getProperty("not.sid");
        AUTH_TOKEN = props.getProperty("not.auth");
        SERVICE_SID = props.getProperty("not.ser_sid");
        servicePhone = props.getProperty("not.servicePhone");


        String command ="curl -X POST https://verify.twilio.com/v2/Services/" + SERVICE_SID + "/Verifications --data-urlencode To=+" + phone +
                " --data-urlencode Channel=sms -u " + ACCOUNT_SID + ":" + AUTH_TOKEN;

        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        process.getInputStream();

        return null ;
    }

    @Override
    public String verify(long phone, int otp) throws IOException {

        String command ="curl -X POST https://verify.twilio.com/v2/Services/" + SERVICE_SID + "/Verifications --data-urlencode To=+" + phone +
                " --data-urlencode Code="+ otp +" -u " + ACCOUNT_SID + ":" + AUTH_TOKEN;
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        process.getInputStream();

        return null;
    }
}
```

Here is the response I get in the postman.

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-04-21T17:16:55.855+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "The number  is unverified. Trial accounts cannot send messages to unverified numbers; verify  at twilio.com/user/account/phone-numbers/verified, or purchase a Twilio number to send messages to unverified numbers.",
    "path": "/api/v1/notifications"
}
```

Comment: Is this a Twilio Trial account? https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360036052753-Twilio-Free-Trial-Limitations

Comment: Yes, a trial account. Is it not possible using a trial account? But the OTP delivers to the phone number.

Comment: @Alan Verify Services Logs also shows the status as approved. But not showing the number in the verified phone numbers list.

Comment: I don't believe it is possible with a trial account. Verify doesn't use a From number in your account.

Comment: Verify Services Logs also shows the status as approved for that new phone number when the OTP is submitted?